# How to deal with avro schema for internal kafka-streams topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We are using Avro schemes for our kafka topics which represent a "public" interface. When such a topic is now consumed in a Kafka-Streams application and a stateful operation is called, the same schema is automatically registered with an internal name again.

What is the common way to deal with that? Those topics and state-stores will never be consumed by anyone else than my application so I don't see the point of publishing that schema to the registry. Is there a way to only use some locally available schema or at least not publish the schema multiple times for every internal topic again?

Answer (score 0):

> not publish the schema multiple times for every internal topic again

You can modify the Serde for each step of your Topology, but then you'd unnecessarily be marshaling data back and forth between different data formats (one with a registry ID, and one without). This would ultimately slow your processing down. When you use AvroSerde + SpecificRecord subclasses, every schema already is local... That won't prevent HTTP requests from hitting the registry with the `TopicNameStrategy` class configured for each internal topic, however.

Your Registry Server subject list is not part of the public API. It is private.

Comment: Actually changing the Serde for the internal topics to a different data format is exactly what I wanted to avoid since I want to benefit for the smaller size of the avro messages to keep my state smaller. What I did now, is a new `SubjectNameStrategy` where I can configure a fixed subject name for a specific type.

Comment: I said modify, rather than use a different one. Reconfiguring a new AvroSerde rather than use the same default one, is still modifying it

Answer (score -2):

I think the best solution is to disable automatic schema registration by setting the configuration parameter `auto.register.schemas=false`, and to use Schema Registry instead.

**PS:**
auto.register.schemas=false should be set in **the client side**

See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/security/index.html

Comment: Actually I have auto registering disabled but kafka-streams then exprects schemas present in the schema registry with generated subject names like `my-streams-application-KSTREAM-TOTABLE-STATE-STORE-0000000006-changelog`, and that for each stateful operation so I would have to add my schema to the schema registry multiple times with different subject names.

Comment: where did you set auto.register.schemas=false ?

Comment: In the properties of my kafka streams application.

Comment: What do you mean "use Schema Registry instead"? `auto.register.schemas=false` is only valid when the Registry + `AvroSerde` **is used**